# Multiline Regex not catching the correct mask

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm trying to catch a tag with a special syntax in a file with this regex :

```
([a-z0-9 >}\/])(\{(var)\:([a-z0-9\_\/\-\.]+)([\?0-9]+)*\})([a-z0-9 {<\/])
```

The tag looks like :

```
 {var:contactText}
```

But as you can see in my regex, I want to catch what's before and after the {var:something}. My expression work fine except when the expression is alone in a line.
I've had `m` flag to prevent the problem but that's still not working.

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/6T6OJm/1/

Am I missing something? It seems to be the last part with `([a-z0-9 {<\/])` which doesn't accept line break, so what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the cat, the "multiline" modifier is a false friend. The m modifier doesn't mean the pattern will run magically over multiple lines, It only changes the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors (from start/end of the string to start/end of the line).

All what you need is to figure potential white characters using the `\s` class (that includes also the carriage return `\r` and the newline `\n` characters).

```
~
    ([a-z0-9 >}/])
    \s* ( { (var) : ([a-z0-9_/.-]+) ([?0-9]+)? } ) \s*
    ([a-z0-9 {</])
~xi
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dkwaqJ/1)

Note that many characters in the pattern doesn't need to be escaped.
Since the pattern is a bit long, I used the x modifier to not take in account spaces in the pattern: it's more readable.

Not sure that all the capture groups are useful.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the "m flag", I would never have found !

Comment: @Camille: the different modifiers are described in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) but some of them are missing and can be found in the PCRE documentation : http://www.pcre.org/pcre2.txt